# copyInputStreamToFile method does not exist

Tags: java, maven, file-io

I'm trying to use the copyInput method in my code, but seems like Intellij told me that the method does not exist

FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(response.getEntity().getContent(), downloadedFile);

I'm using the code from here

http://ardesco.lazerycode.com/index.php/2012/07/how-to-download-files-with-selenium-and-why-you-shouldnt/

But it seems like the method exist here

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html

I'm using maven, I tried with 2.0, 2.1, 2.4 without luck

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Java 1.8

Here is the error message

Error:(201, 22) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method copyInputStreamToFile(java.io.InputStream,java.io.File)
  location: class org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils

[image]

Comment: What's the complete, exact error message?

Comment: What version of Apache `commons.io` are you using?

Comment: @Andreas I have edited the question, you can see more details on it

Comment: Obviously you are using the wrong version of `FileUtils`. But this isn't rocket science, you can write it yourself in about five lines of Java.

Comment: @EJP could you be more specific? What do you mean with the wrong version? What should be the correct?

Comment: You are using an earlier version that didn't have this method. Get the latest version. I don't know what it is any more than you do.

Comment: @EJP so according to the documentation the method exist since 2.0 https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyInputStreamToFile(java.io.InputStream, java.io.File), and I tried with 2.0, 2.1, 2.4, 2.5 and same issue. Also I tried using the complete reference org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile and same error...

Comment: A few sanity checks... 
Please verify you're getting the same error even if you build your project using Maven directly from command-line. This will ensure IDE is not interfering in any way.
Also, please run [`mvn dependency:tree`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html) to verify Maven is selecting the correct version of the library.

Comment: @AntonKoscejev I tried the mvn command and seems like I have the 2.5 version [INFO] |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: I also try mvn clean test but I got the same error /FileDownloader.java:[201,22] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method copyInputStreamToFile(java.io.InputStream,java.io.File)
[ERROR] location: class org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils

Comment: @msiles everything you have looks good, so that is indeed very strange, as this should not be happening. Most likely the cause is some oversight somewhere. Can you provide additional details about your project? Is it a single-module project? Could you perhaps create a minimal project archive that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Is it possible that you're somehow receiving an incorrect version of commons-io? For example, do you use some proxy to get Maven dependencies? Latest IntelliJ IDEA contains a decompiler that will be used automatically to show you code, when you ctrl+click into `FileUtils`. If you check this, you can verify that `FileUtils` do indeed contain the method.
Alternatively you can verify the downloaded jar itself by finding it in your local repository (normally under `~/.m2/repository`).

Comment: @AntonKoscejev thanks for your help, No Proxy... I also tried on a new project and seems to be working fine, but somehow the version does not have that method on my project... I'm importing a jar from another module, probably this is getting an earlier version.

Answer (score 4):

You probably have another (older) `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils` on your classpath, which would explain the issues you're having. Most likely one of your dependencies has an old `org.apache.commons:commons-io` artifact on the classpath. Due to the groupId difference, Maven considers them different artifacts and puts both on the classpath.

If that is what's really happening, you can explicitly forbid maven from including this transitive dependency by adding an `exclusion` to the dependency that references the old commons-io (even if it depends on it transitively):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>offending.artifact.groupId</groupId>
  <artifactId>offending.artifact.artifactId</artifactId>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: To find the offending class in IntelliJ IDEA: Menu > Navigate > Class > type `FileUtils` > (might need to select "Include non-project files").
This will show you the list of `FileUtils` classes available on your classpath, including the (possibly transitive) dependency that contains it.

If you already know that it's definitely from `org.apache.commons:commons:io`, you can check `dependency:tree` to find which dependency references it transitively, although it's also possible to do this using IntelliJ maven-related features.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to see the wrong version using the menu options "To find the offending class in IntelliJ IDEA: Menu > Navigate > Class > type FileUtils", there were like 4 FileUtils,

I imported the correct version on the jar file and it fix the problem, Thanks @Anton.

Answer (score 1):

`FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(inputStream,file);`

This function may be used in versions larger than two (2). You need to add this line to the gradle:

`implementation 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'`

Comment: `FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(inputStream,file)` is written in `org.apache.commons.io`, which therefore makes it necessary to include the library. +1

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, but it seems that I had old version of version of commons-io. I fixed it by changing version to 2.6 in pom.xml file.